# PHP form is not working for me

Tags: php

I'm making a very simple fishing game. the user has to buy pots, easy enough.
now the form for buying pots looks very simple

```
title1 - box1 - submit_buttom1

title2 - box2 - submit_buttom2
```

Now when the user inputs information into `box1` and then they click "enter" on there keyboard the `submit_button1` is activated and the script runs through.
but when the user input information into `box2` and they click "enter" on there keyboard, `submit_button1` is activated.
Now I can understand how this can sound very confusing so I have put it online

[link](http://www.roundaboutmk.com/problem)

this is my script

```
 echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\" >\n";
 echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php\">\n";
 echo "<tr><td>North Pot</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"northpot\"></td>\n";
 echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit1\" name=\"submit1\" value=\"Buy\"></td></tr>\n";
 echo "</forum></table>";

 echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\" >\n";
 echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php\">\n";
 echo "<tr><td>South Pot</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"southpot\"></td>\n";
 echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit2\" name=\"submit2\" value=\"Buy\"></td></tr>\n";
 echo "</forum></table>";
```

if you need anymore information, please just say

Comment: will do, i wish i could choose more than one person :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change `</forum>` to `</form>`

Comment: thank you, that worked great, i cant please i missed that, i had looked through the code like 30 times and did not even see that

Comment: No problem, just use validator or some IDE with highlight of pairs of tags (so you can see that you missed closing tag)

Answer (score 4):

You are generating invalid HTML. A form cannot be a child element of a `<table>` or a parent element of `<tr>`. It is also spelt `form` and not `forum`.

It is likely that your browser is recovering for this error by moving the form element to *after* the table but leaving all the form controls inside the table.

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Your closing form, tag spells forum. Should be `</form>`

Comment: ahaha, thanks, i did not see that